# Delete songs manually on ipod Touch (without the help of iTunes)

Tags: ipod-touch, macos

Is it possible to delete songs manually on an iPod Touch (without the help of iTunes) as it is possible for podcasts and videocasts?

Comment: ipod touch or classic?

Comment: It's an Apple iPod Touch...

Answer (score 2):

Not in the current iOS version